# how to specify '--relative' in a git alias

Tags: git

I am trying to write a git alias that will create a patch for a single commit, that I can then apply to an upstream repository.

This is what I have so far:

```
pa = !sh -c 'git diff --relative "$1"^ "$1"' -
```

So on the command line I say:

```
$ git pa SHA
```

and I get a diff output.

My problem is that the --relative option is having no effect. I want the diff to be relative to the current folder so that the patch applies correctly within the upstream repository. For example, I am in myproject/libraries/external and I have committed changes within this folder. I now want to make a patch I can commit or submit to an issue queue for the external project, hence the need for the --relative option.

(BTW: I am aware of format-patch, but it doesn't do what I want at all. I don't want mail files, I want patch files I can read and upload to issue trackers.)

Answer (score 1):

Non-Git aliases ( those starting with `!` ) are always executed from the top-level dir of a repo.

So for the alias that you have defined, you will get the diff as though you had never used the `--relative` flag

The only option I see for you is to set the alias like:

```
[alias]
pa = diff --relative
```

and use it as `git pa SHA^ SHA` ( which is not much of a shorter alias )

Comment: Heh -- I already have 'dfr' as an alias for diff --relative ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the shell aliases being executed at the top of the repo -- at least now I know why it's not working :)

Answer (score 0):

What about `git diff SHA^ SHA -- .`? That should be relative to the current working directory. I've never heard of the `--relative` option and cannot find it in the [git diff manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) either.

```
pa = !sh -c 'git diff "$1"^! -- .' -
```

(`SHA^!` is just a neat way of saying `SHA --not(all of SHA's parents)` – might not be the output you expect for a merge commit)

Comment: Funny, I can see it right there in the link you give:

--relative[=<path>]

    When run from a subdirectory of the project, it can be told to exclude changes outside the directory and show pathnames relative to it with this option. When you are not in a subdirectory (e.g. in a bare repository), you can name which subdirectory to make the output relative to by giving a <path> as an argument.

Comment: 'git diff SHA^ SHA -- .' is not giving the desired result on the command line I'm afraid.

Comment: I cannot access kernel.org from here, but used another website to check for --relative. Must be a paramater only recently added. `git diff … -- path` should exclude everything not in path from the diff, am I missing something?

Comment: It's not just about the files to exclude -- in fact, that part is mostly irrelevant as my commits are contained to that folder anyway. The point is that the filepaths in the patch should be relative, which is what --relative gives you. Hence 'a/foo.php' instead of 'a/libraries/external/foo.php'.

Comment: I'm not aware of this functionality in Git, since it operates on the whole tree. Maybe someone else can shed some light. Alternatively, use `sed(1)` to normalize your paths? And also try `--relative=.`

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the `--relative` option with `--no-prefix`:

```
git diff --no-prefix --relative "$1"^ "$1"
```

Maybe you got confused by the prefixes that git diff adds to its output by default?

Answer (score 0):

As [manojlds points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336393/691281), non-Git aliases (those starting with "!") are always executed from the top-level directory of a repository, so this isn't going to work.

Instead you could use a bash function (or your shell's equivalent):

```
git-pa() { git diff --relative "$1"^ "$1" "${@:2}"; }
```

(the `"${@:2}"` passes all subsequent parameters unchanged, in case you want to pass additional refinements - [see documentation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#range_of_positional_parameters)).